# Expand a div on x axis based on the size of content until it reaches max width

Tags: css

So I'm making a chat app, and I'm trying to expand a div based on its content on the x axis until it reaches the max-width. Then I want the div to expand downwards. I was wondering if this is possible and if it is, is there a way to make it expand to the left as well instead of just the right? Thanks!

Comment: please show your code in https://jsfiddle.net/ to explain your question

Comment: sure, not really sure if it helps with the context of the question though. https://jsfiddle.net/bxvqw34w/1/

Comment: Use `display: inline-block` instead of `block`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You only need to set max-width and white-space: normal and direction rtl to expand to the left;
for example

```
#resize{max-width: 300px;white-space: normal;direction: rtl;}
```

IGNORE WHAT I WROTE i tested it again and i found that you need to have 2 divs

```
<div id = "resize">
<div id = "text">
some text
</div>
</div>
```

and your css

```
#resize {
max-width: 300px;
width: auto;
}
#text {
white-space: normal;
direction: rtl;
width: auto;
display: inline-block;
}
```

I think this is what you want!!1

Comment: so it works great, however do you know how i would make it so like there is a margin that expands on the opposite direction (that way the messages are below the previous div)

Comment: nvm I figured it out, you would just add another div to handle the margins :P Thanks man!